# Handling S3 File downloads without resource exhaustion

Tags: go, amazon-s3, go-gin

I have a go-gin application, it allows for the uploading and downloading of multiple file types in S3.

All files prior to getting uploaded to s3 are encrypted using the the AWS s3cryptoclient, using AES GCM, with a key from KMS. So as far as the s3 bucket understand everything is in binary.

I can use the SDK command of getObject to download a file to the server decrypt it and then  using a io.write(tempfile) I then could offer this file to the client for downloading.

The issue here S3 contains files that are 10gb in size, and this server will be accessed by multiple users daily. As we can see writing temp files on a server with even 16gb of ram will exhaust the memory quickly, and lets also note the cost of running such server.

The bottleneck is that the files need to be decrypted prior to getting served, a S3 persigned url would be sufficient in this use case, although decryption is not something offered by s3 presigned urls unless its was encryption done by the customer, in our case AWS is handling the encryption, so this solution is not viable.

Does anyone have any tips or possible use cases to overcome this issue, where we could write the file directly to the client possibly, using go-gin/NGINX.

Current handling of file downloads by user

```
s3FileStream, _ := s3c.GetBucketItem(&utils.S3ObjectBucketInput{
    Bucket: "bucketName",
    Key:    "UserFileName"
})

fileBody, err := io.ReadAll(s3FileStream.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

fileExtension := s3FileStream.Metadata["X-Amz-Meta-Type"]

err = ioutil.WriteFile("file" + *fileExtension, fileBody, 600) // temp file
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, string(fileBody))
c.Done()
```

}

Comment: "as far as the s3 bucket understand everything is in binary." this is true anyway.  S3 only stores "objects" and considers their content an opaque series of bytes.  "in our case AWS is handling the encryption" is it?   Sounds like you're doing the encryption yourself client-side as you upload the object.  You probably don't need to, as you can associate the KMS key with the bucket and let S3 handle the encryption; then S3 pre-signed URLs would work for you.

Comment: "writing temp files on a server with even 16gb of ram will exhaust the memory quickly" Your technique is to blame here. `fileBody, err := io.ReadAll(s3FileStream.Body)` you have to fit all of `fileBody` in memory at the same time to do it this way.  Instead, you should use `io.Copy`to stream the s3 body to the open temp file.  You'd still need enough disk space to fit the entire s3 object, but at least you don't need it in memory as well as disk space.  You don't need disk space at all if you can stream the S3 data straight to the client.

Comment: The files need to encrypted prior to uploading, this is a compliance request, and yes you are correct we are doing this on the client,  when I typed "aws is handling the encryption" it was in terms of the encryption process as its handled by AWS s3CryptoClient, we did not write the encryption methods or have a 3rd party doing so. Thanks for alerting me to ```io.Copy```.

Comment: Which exact library is s3cryptoclient ?  I would need  to see if they support streaming in the documentation

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.DataFromReader can stream out if "s3CryptoClient" can provide an io.Reader.

Comment: aws-s3 crypto client repo https://github.com/aws/amazon-s3-encryption-client-go  Regarding the ```c.DataFromReader``` is what the poster below specified as well, seems to be the most viable, just having issues with getting the stream to download with chrome giving "cloud finish download" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to write the object directly to the client as the response body:

```
s3FileStream, _ := s3c.GetBucketItem(&utils.S3ObjectBucketInput{
    Bucket: "bucketName",
    Key:    "UserFileName",
})
fileExtension := s3FileStream.Metadata["X-Amz-Meta-Type"]
c.DataFromReader(http.StatusCreated, 0, "application/data",
    s3FileStream.Body,
    map[string]string{"Content-Dispositon": "attachment; filename=" + "file" + *fileExtension})
c.Done()
```